# Is there a way to make multiple ring buffers into the raster format?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.0, buffer

Is there a way to make multiple ring buffers into the raster format? The distances are 0.25,0.5,0.75 & 1. Since they are less than 1 it shows as an error while using the polygon to raster tool. Eventually, I want to reclassify them as ranks & eventually use weighted overlay for the analysis. (ArcGIS Pro)

Comment: What cellsize are you using for buffers so small?or is it that your data is in geographic coordinates? are you omitting the cellsize parameter of the tool leaving it to default value? You could try euclidean distance and then a Con(VALUE < 0.25,0.25,Con(Value < 0.5,0.5... up to your buffer distances or reclassify to get an integer raster but you will still want to use a very small cell size to get the resolution of your ring buffers.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS in use.  You have a 10.0 tag and ArcGIS Pro in the same question, and that's just *wrong*

Answer (score 1):

With such small distances that will ultimately be transferred to weights, if you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension, I would try the [Euclidean Distance](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/euclidean-distance.htm) tool. You can set a max distance to limit the processing and it will essentially create a continuous raster of distances from your course, up to the max distance.

Comment: That works but the output cellsize *must* be smaller than 0.25 (the smallest buffer).. I have a suspicion that the OPs problem comes from omitting the cellsize parameter which has defaulted to 1, hence the error; on a 1 metre cell size all the buffers will fall within the same cell or adjacent cell.